# How to boost the speed of downloading files in the background in Android?

Tags: android, inputstream

I am developing an app (for both Android and iPhone). Actually, in my app I have to download lot of videos in background (using a background service, IntentService) as well as I have a screen showing the progress of downloads (using an Activity which has UI for showing download progress). But I don't know why the download speed is too less as compared to download speed for the same app in iPhone.

Also, after each download of video, I am marking that video as downloaded in the database. And this happens for all videos.

Is the database calls a problem for slow downloads of files in android?
Since the same functionality does not affect the download speed of files in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the Byte size of your inputstream

**Update:** 
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8748960/928591)

Comment: increasing the byte size has helped me :) thanx dude.. but is there a way to increase it a bit more or more precisely what should be the size I should use?

Comment: I am not behind a computer right now,  but when I am later today ill get back at you on this

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement some sort of download accelerator which downloads a single file by splitting it in segments and using several simultaneous connections to download these segments from a the server. First you should check if the server Accepts `byte-ranges` and then specify *byte-ranges* to download in a multi-threaded way. At last you just merge back the segments into a complete file.

Look into these documents for more info:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5

Page 128: 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt

Also look up Java API **URLConnection.setRequestProperty**

However, I think the slow download is mostly because of your network bandwidth and server's upload speed.